# Filter messages on chat application for specifc words using .allow or .deny

Tags: meteor

As for the new meteor release, I`d like to understand how can I forbid messages with certain words to be added to a collection.

Let's say I'm passing: `Messages.insert({message:"Holy ducking smokes", at: new Date()});`

What should the code within `if (Meteor.is_server)` be like so it would block any entries containing "duck"?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
Messages.deny({
  insert: function(userId, doc) {
    if (doc.message.match(/\bduck\b/i)) return true;
    return false;
  }
}
```

That will deny the client from inserting the record if the message contains the bounded word "duck". Obviously you could execute other logic there (eg. censoring) if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

One way I could do this was setting a `.allow` within the `Meteor.is_server` to test if the value differs from what I`m filtering.

It should look something like this:

```
    if (Meteor.is_server) {
        Messages.allow({
            insert: function (userId, doc) {
                var currentMessage = Messages.findOne({message:doc.message}) ;
                if (doc.message == 'duck') { //here i`m filtering stirngs 
                    return false;
                } else { return true; }
            },
            update: function () { (...) },
            remove: function () { (...) },
        });
    }
```

But I guess using methods would be a better approach to this, as it makes sense to use a single validation rule to both server and client side.